# linux setting uid_map under sudo

Tags: linux, containers

Suppose I have some process `A` which `clone`s process `B` with flags `CLONE_NEWUSER | CLONE_NEWPID | CLONE_NEWNS` and this process `B` has pid=PID. Then in process `A` I write to `/proc/PID/uid_map` string `0 1000 1` (1000 is uid of my user).

If I run `A` just under my user `./A` this works fine and in process `B` `getuid()` gives me `0`. But if I run `A` like `sudo ./A` then `getuid()` in `B` gives me 65534 (`nobody`).

As I searched through `sudo` code it does not create any new namespaces. So my question is what is happening here and why under sudo I can not set mapping `0 1000 1` properly?

**UPDATE**

Also, if I add suid to `A`:

```
$ sudo su
# chown 0:0 A
# chmod u+s A
# exit
$ ./A
```

Then `B` gives me `0` again.

Comment: I don't like `sudo su`, have you tried `sudo -i` first?

Comment: @LapshinDmitry the question is not about this part. Here I just set SUID bit for my script.

Comment: I just think that double-layer suid (`sudo` and `su`) could have some side-effects.